# Nested block within a reference not rendering when using ->getChildHtml()

Tags: magento, block, magento-layout-xml

this is my layout xml:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="page.brand" template="page/brand.phtml" />
            <block type="catalog/product_list" template="page/accessories.phtml">
                 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" as="filter_menu" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/> 
            </block>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

And from within page.accessories.phtml, inside some div block i call:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('filter_menu') ?>
```

but nothing renders out.  Why is that?

this is code from the layered phtml file:

```
<div class="oh_shit"></div>
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Options') ?></p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can't display Layered Navigation on a non-anchor category.

Comment: hmm the category is set to anchored in the admin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. i got it.  i accidentally deleted the name attribute on the block with type="product_list".  when i re-added the name="product_list" it worked.

Comment: I had the same problem, figured out that without a name Magento could not set the parent block. See: http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/09/magento-layout-getchildhtml-mit-leerem-ergebnis/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your blocks in your layout xml to:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="page.brand" template="page/brand.phtml" />
        <block type="catalog/product_list" template="page/accessories.phtml">
             <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" as="filter_menu" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/> 
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: sorry, i hadn't included the layered xml change in my post but i changed that as well. its identical to the default layout as well.  it should be rendering shouldn't it?

Comment: ok it works. i had noticed that it is outputting the gethtml but inside the phtml it has a couple of if clauses, and it turns out for some reason that the if is returning false so it wasnt outputting anything.  i put a temporary div block outside the if and it was creating the div block.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: it looks like canShowBlock is returning false, any idea why

Comment: How are you referencing canShowBlock?  Can you post the code?

Comment: ok i edited my post, it is exactly the same as the original, i haven't changed anything other than the layout xml files.

Comment: looks like i spoke too soon, it looks like getchildhtml wasnt being called at all. i had been outputting the block in the reference block as well as putting it in the nested block. so i was printing the blocks both times only the nested one wasnt being printed. no idea why its not working.

Comment: after debugging it looks like the getchild on the product_list block object is returning false.  there is no child, only a "toolbar" child, does this have to do with the type that catalog/navigation and catalog/product_list don't interact?